# PostgreSQL select distinct with like condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-performance

I have large table with few millions of records. Each record contain type, which came from outer source. I know that number of types is around 100 - 200.

I need to get subset of types for search hint.

I need something like this:

```
select distinct my_type from my_table where my_type like '%XXX%';
```

But it is very slow. 4-5 second for 8M records.

My question: can I somehow improve performance of this select or use different query?

Comment: Have you tried Elasticsearch?

Comment: When you use `like` with ` '%XXX%'` the database engine will probably not be able to use any indexes on the field being compared, it will therefore have to scan all records, which can result in slow queries over large datasets.  You can use `explain` ( https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-explain.html ) to investigate.   What indexes do you have on the table ?

Comment: I don't have any index related to this field. And yes, I know that db using full scan. So I looking for something which will compact amount of data to number of types, than execute like operator. I'm not DB expert, I played with indexes/group by etc, but nothing helped.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the `create table` statements for the tables in question and the execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, verbose)`**. [**Formatted text**](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 2):

`distinct` and `group by` take different code paths, so you might test each of these:

```
select my_type
  from (select distinct my_type from my_table) as t 
  where my_type like '%XXX%';

select my_type
  from (select my_type from my_table group by my_type) as t 
  where my_type like '%XXX%';
```

Comment: The problem is not in 'like', but in number of like calls. I don't need 8m like calls, I need to get 200 unique types, than execute like on them.

Comment: Both distinct and group by - working same time (full scan). Can you suggest which index I have to add to make it work faster?

Comment: @Nosyara do you have an index on `my_type`?

Comment: @Nosyara This might be a good case for a [materialized view](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/rules-materializedviews.html)